# Сортировка по результатам поиска в 1С-Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, php

Доброго времени суток, знатоки, еще раз!

Снова возникла проблема с работой битрикса. У меня настроен поиск товаров с помощью  sphinx. Сейчас стоит задача настроить сортировку найденных товаров по пользовательским полям. Казалось бы не сложно. Но если я правильно понял документацию, то сортировку результатов поиска можно производить только по полям rank и date. Пробовал пойти тем же путем, что и для CIBlockElement, но тщетно. Может, кто сталкивался с подобным? И еще мне предстоит после этого еще и фильтрацию производить по результатам поиска. Если кто подскажет и на этот счет, буду благодарен!

Answer (score 2):

Если кому интересно, то я нашел способ обойти этот промах битрикса. Но сразу оговорюсь, что у него есть и серьезный минус - если вы используете пагинацию на сайте, то при этом способе фильтрация и сортировка будут работать только на той странице, которой вы находитесь.

Спасает нас result_modifier и функция PHP - usort. Для начала создадим в init.php класс:

```
class CCabinet_SortObject {

function __cmp_ValueOf($a, $b, $name, $order) {
    if(is_set($a[$name]) && is_set($b[$name])) {
        if($order == 'ASC')
            return ($a[$name]<$b[$name])?true:false;
        elseif($order == 'DESC')return ($b[$name]>$a[$name])?false:true;
    }
}

function cmp_ВАШ_ПАРМЕТР_ВАШ_ПОРЯДОК($a, $b) {
    return CCabinet_SortObject::__cmp_ValueOf($a, $b, "ПАРАМЕТР_СОРТИРОВКИ", "ПОРЯДОК_СОРТИРОВКИ");
}
function cmp_ВАШ_ПАРМЕТР_ВАШ_ПОРЯДОК($a, $b) {
    return CCabinet_SortObject::__cmp_ValueOf($a, $b, "ПАРАМЕТР_СОРТИРОВКИ", "ПОРЯДОК_СОРТИРОВКИ");
}
```

Он позволит нам сортировать готовый массив после поиска. Вызывать мы его будем в result_modifier таким способом:

```
if(isset($_GET["by"]) && isset($_GET["order"]))
{
          usort($arResult['МАССИВ'],array("CCabinet_SortObject","cmp_".$_GET["by"]."_".$_GET["order"]));
 }
```

То есть мы указываем наш массив, который надо отсортировать, и потом by - по какому полю сортировать, order - порядок сортировки. Собственно это все. 
Фильтрацию, думаю, особого смысла нет расписывать -  там все просто. Надо только отловить наш параметр и по нему фильтровать.

Answer (score 1):

Для себя решил так. В component.php в папке компонента поиска(скопировал в свое пространство) сделал.

Забираем полный список товаров

```
$obSearch->Search($arFilter, $aSort, $exFILTER);
```

Потом беру получаю массив значений:

```
        $ar2 = $obSearch->GetNext();
        $i = 0;
        while($ar2){

            $ar2 = $obSearch->GetNext();
            if($ar2["ITEM_ID"]){
                $fullArr[$i] = $ar2;
                $rs = CIBlockElement::GetList(
                    array("SORT" => "ASC", "ID" => "ASC"),
                    array(
                        "IBLOCK_ID" => PRODUCTS_IBLOCK_ID,
                        "ID" => $ar2["ITEM_ID"]
                    ),
                    false,
                    false,
                    array("ID","CATALOG_QUANTITY")
                );

                while ($ar = $rs->GetNext()){
                        $fullArr[$i]['CATALOG_QUANTITY'] = $ar['CATALOG_QUANTITY'];
                }
            }

            $i++;

        }
```

Сортирую через usort

```
            function sortByQuantity($a,$b){
            return ((int)$a["CATALOG_QUANTITY"] > (int)$b["CATALOG_QUANTITY"])?-1:1; 
        }
        usort($fullArr, "sortByQuantity");
```

И загоняем обратно в CDBResult

```
$obSearch ->InitFromArray($fullArr);
```